# South, loaddata and migrations with Date filter

Tags: django-south

Is there a way to migrate all apps with a date filter?

I have several dumps from several states of my django project. They are produced with dumpdata command.
I have a testcaseinit script that loads one of those dumps.

The thing is, loaddata does not recreate the database with its structure.
I have the script below but it migrates to many things right at the beginning :

```
./drop.py                     # a home-made script that drops all tables from database
./manage.py migrate --all     # creates the whole database as the current version of the project
./manage.py loaddata $1       # loads the fixture
```

But I need something like:

```
./drop.py
./manage.py migrate --all --until-date=creation_date_of_$1
./manage.py loaddata $1
./manage.py migrate --all
```